# Existing constants (e.g. constructors) in type class instantiations

Tags: typeclass, isabelle

Consider this Isabelle code

```
theory Scratch imports Main begin

datatype Expr = Const nat | Plus Expr Expr
```

it is quite reasonable to instantiate the `plus` type class to get nice syntax for the `Plus` constructor:

```
instantiation Expr :: plus
begin
  definition "plus_Exp = Plus"
instance..
end
```

But now, `+` and `Plus` are still separate constants. In particular, I cannot (easily) use `+` in a function definition, e.g.

```
fun swap where
   "swap (Const n) = Const n"
 | "swap (e1 + e2) = e2 + e1"
```

will print

```
Malformed definition:
Non-constructor pattern not allowed in sequential mode.
⋀e1 e2. swap (e1 + e2) = e2 + e1
```

How can I instantiate a type class with an *existing* constant instead of defining a new one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Type class instantiations in Isabelle always introduce new constants for the parameters of the type class. Thus, you cannot say that `plus` (written infix as `+`) shall be the same as `Plus`. However, you can go the other way around, namely instantiate the type class first and only later declare the operations on the type class as the constructors of the datatype.

One such case can be found in the theory [Extended_Nat](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/repos/isabelle/file/5ae2a2e74c93/src/HOL/Library/Extended_Nat.thy#l28) where the type `enat` is constructed manually via a `typedef`, then the infinity type class is instantiated, and finally `enat` is declared as a datatype with two constructors using `old_rep_datatype`. However, this is a very simple case of a non-recursive datatype without type variables. In case of your expression example, I recommend that you do the following:

1. Define a type `expr_aux` with `datatype expr_aux = Const_aux nat | Plus_aux expr_aux expr_aux`.
2. Define a `expr` as a type copy of `expr_aux` with `typedef expr = "UNIV :: expr_aux set"` and `setup_lifting type_definition_expr`.
3. Lift the constructor `Const_aux` to `expr` with the lifting package: `lift_definition Const :: "nat => expr" is Const_aux .`
4. Instantiate the type class `plus`:

```
instantiation expr :: plus begin
lift_definition plus_expr :: "expr => expr => expr" is Plus_aux .
instance ..
end
```

5. Register `expr` as a datatype with `old_rep_datatype expr Const "plus :: expr => _"` and an appropriate proof (use `transfer`).
6. Define an `abbreviation Plus :: "expr => expr => expr" where "Plus == plus"`

Obviously, this is very tedious. If you just want to use pattern matching in functions, you can use the `free_constructor` command to register the constructors `Const` and `plus :: expr => expr => expr` as new constructors of `expr` after the instantiation. If you then add "Plus = plus" as a simp rule, this should be almost as good as the tedious way. Yet, I do not know how well the various packages (in particular case syntax) cope with this re-registration of the constructors.